# Story music files paths on database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to scan a folder on my drive and store every music (.mp3 .m4a) files paths on a database with php. I found the below script to recursivly echo files one by one as a tree but how can i use it to echo the full path on the drive and store every path on a table on mysql database?

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
$ffs = scandir($dir);
echo '<ol>';
foreach($ffs as $ff){
    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
        echo '<li>'.$ff;
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('PATH');
```

Comment: use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT|_ROOT'] . listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff)` or if on Linux create a symbolic link to the music directory in the *web root* and maybe it works on windows with a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should solve your problem with just some supplements (in this example with Laravel Query Builder):

```
function listFolderFiles($dir)
   {
   $ffs = scandir($dir);

   foreach($ffs as $ff)
      {
      if($ff != "." && $ff != "..")
         {
         echo $dir."  -  ".$ff."<br>";
         DB::table("musicfiles")->insert("path" => $dir, "file" => $ff);

         if(is_dir($dir."/".$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir."/".$ff);
         }
      }
   }

listFolderFiles("/directory");
```